# Mongodb match a field only if specific value exists

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am making a dating app, where use have gender filter options (male, female, any). When user selects `any` I dont want to filter any `gender` field. I only want to filter/match `gender` field when user selects `male` or `female` options.

```js
const matching_users = await User
  .aggregate([{
    $match: {
      $and: [{
          uid: {
            $in: matches
          }
        },
        {
          account_setuped: true
        },
        {
          $or: [{
            gender: settings.gender_filter === "any" ? "male" : settings.gender_filter
          }, {
            gender: settings.gender_filter === "any" ? "female" : settings.gender_filter
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  }, ])
```

is there any better options other than this?

Answer (score 0):

For the gender comparison part, I think can be simplified as:

```
.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    $and: [
      { 
        // Filter 1  
      },
      { 
        // Filter 2 
      },
      {
          $expr: {
            $or: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "any",
                  settings.gender_filter
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$gender",
                  settings.gender_filter
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7mqcezwwH6z)

---

Another approach with `switch`

```
{
  "$switch": {
    "branches": [
      {
        "case": {
          $eq: [
            "any",
            settings.gender_filter                  
          ]
        },
        "then": true
      },
    ],
    default: {
      $eq: [
        "$gender",
        settings.gender_filter           
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (`$switch`)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3bh0QRXIY9Y)

Note: To test the demo, replace the value which contains the comment:

> // settings.gender_filter